# How to speed up this Pandas dataframe operation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with pandas to make some calculations on a list of news articles, namely to get averages of NLP data when grouped by date and also by source to output into a JS chart. With 20k records, the operations take between 2 and 3 seconds. I'd like to get it down to less than .5 if possible. The code is:

```
articles = [{'title': "article title", 'rounded_polarity': 63, 'rounded_subjectivity': 45, 'source_name': 'foxnews', 'day': '2020-01-11 00:00:00+00:00'}, ...]

def get_averages(articles):
    data_frame = DataFrame(articles)
    grouped_by_day = data_frame.groupby(['day']).mean()
    grouped_by_source = data_frame.groupby(['source_name']).mean()

    grouped_by_day_dict = grouped_by_day.to_dict()
    grouped_by_source_dict = grouped_by_source.to_dict()
    max_sentiments = grouped_by_source.idxmax().to_dict()
    min_sentiments = grouped_by_source.idxmin().to_dict()

    total_avg_subjectivity = statistics.mean([v for k, v in grouped_by_source_dict['rounded_subjectivity'].items()])
    total_avg_sentiment = statistics.mean([v for k, v in grouped_by_source_dict['rounded_polarity'].items()])

    return {
        'most_positive_source': max_sentiments['rounded_polarity'],
        'least_positive_source': min_sentiments['rounded_polarity'],
        'most_subjective_source': max_sentiments['rounded_subjectivity'],
        'least_subjective_source': min_sentiments['rounded_subjectivity'],
        'average_sentiment': total_avg_sentiment,
        'average_subjectivity': total_avg_subjectivity,
        'averages_by_day': grouped_by_day_dict,
        'earliest_publish_date': grouped_by_day.index.min(),
        'latest_publish_date': grouped_by_day.index.max()
```

How can I leverage more of pandas built in functionality to speed things up?

Comment: Please provide a sample data: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Edited to include a sample data object

Comment: Why would you convert dataframe to dict and use operations over them?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]? I'll second what @FBruzzesi asked, converting the DataFrames to dictionaries is unlikely to be necessary.

Comment: Also, have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: @FBruzzesi simply, because I don't really know how to ask pandas to perform the operations that corrolate to the Python data structures that I understand. Also, these values are going to end up in a javascript chart and I'll need them as json at the end of the day anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think the pandas and numpy way to go is something very similar to what you have done, just use built-in functions and methods:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

articles = [{'title': "article title", 'rounded_polarity': 63, 'rounded_subjectivity': 45, 'source_name': 'foxnews', 'day': '2020-01-11 00:00:00+00:00'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(articles)
grouped_by_day = df.groupby('day').mean()
grouped_by_source = df.groupby('source_name').mean()


max_sentiments = grouped_by_source.idxmax()
min_sentiments = grouped_by_source.idxmin()

total_avg = np.mean(grouped_by_source.to_numpy()) # equivalent to grouped_by_source.mean() if you don't want to add numpy dependency, however numpy is faster! 

result = {'most_positive_source': max_sentiments['rounded_polarity'],
          'least_positive_source': min_sentiments['rounded_polarity'],
          'most_subjective_source': max_sentiments['rounded_subjectivity'],
          'least_subjective_source': min_sentiments['rounded_subjectivity'],
          'average_sentiment': total_avg['rounded_polarity'],
          'average_subjectivity': total_avg['rounded_subjectivity'],
          'averages_by_day': grouped_by_day.to_dict(),
          'earliest_publish_date': grouped_by_day.index.min(),
          'latest_publish_date': grouped_by_day.index.max()}
```